# How to pass value of field in already executed method?

Tags: c++

I realized that my Stop() method never starts, because Start() method never stops. Tautology, but this is the answer why isn't this working. So, how do I stop my Start() method?

---

I need to change `isTurnedOn` value to `true`/`false` when Start()/Stop() methods being executed. But when I'm executing these methods in the following way: `void main(){sw.Start(); sw.Watch(); sw.Stop();}`  - clock never stops; What am I supposed to do with this to fix it?

```
class Stopwatch {
        bool isTurnedOn; 
    }sw;   
    void Stopwatch::Start() {
        isTurnedOn = true;
    }
    void Stopwatch::Stop() {
        isTurnedOn = false;
    }
    void Stopwatch::Watch() {
    while(isTurnedOn)
    {
    h = hours < 10 ? "0" : "";
    s = seconds < 10 ? "0" : "";
    m = minutes < 10 ? "0" : "";
    cout << h << hours << " : " << m << minutes << " : " << s << seconds;
    Sleep(1000);
    system("cls");
    seconds++;
    if (seconds == 60) {
        minutes++;
        seconds = 0;
        if (minutes == 60) {
            hours++;
            seconds = 0;
            minutes = 0;
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: As written, this will never work without threads (and with threads you'd need synchronization). Investigate state machines and threads.

Comment: you can change `isTurnedOn` inside of loop, or in other thread

Comment: @AlexeyUsachov ok, but how do I know when should I change it?

Comment: Consider stepping through your program with a debugger rather than trying to guess why it doesn't work.

Comment: @loaner9 thats exactly what ive been doing for almost 1 hour. It didnt help me a lot

Comment: @ex1t3 Don't know exactly what you need to do, but if your loop can take all control of the program then you could do short `sleep()` in it to give other processes in system work. and when there would be right condition you can change your `isTurnedOn`

Comment: Well, I realized that my Stop() method never executes. isTurnedOn never goes out of loop, so loop couldnt be stopped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you're trying to implement class `Stopwatch` that would allow you to measure how much time passed since some moment.

Please have a look at [Stopwatch class from C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx), especially at examples. It's one of possible approaches and it's not bad one. This should hint how you can design your class.

The minimal interface can be something like:

```
class Stopwatch
{
public:
    // initialises internal state to the current time
    Stopwatch();

    // returns how many milliseconds elapsed since creation of this instance
    uint64_t elapsed_ms();
}
```

Implement it using [std::chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) library.

Usage example:

```
void heavy_func();

int main()
{
    Stopwatch sw;
    heavy_func();
    auto elapsed_ms = sw.elapsed_ms();
    std::cout << "heavy_func() took " << elapsed_ms << " ms\n";
}
```

You'll need to adapt this to your needs. Try to keep it simple and don't fall into "swiss army knife" hole.

Comment: Thats the problem: I have to avoid using libs like chrono and others. But anyway, Дякую.

Comment: @ex1t3: `chrono` is just the best generic C++ solution because it's standard. If you cannot use it there're number of time-related functions from `C`. Or your system API like `WinAPI` or `posix` or whatever system you're on. The right choice (if you have specific requirements) depends on required timer resolution and its performance, and deserves for a separate question where you can specify more details. На здоров'я :)

Comment: @ex1t3 What exactly are your constraints?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that your control flow becomes trapped in an infinite loop that cannot escape without threads. To avoid the added complexity of threads, the solution becomes: Extract the control flow from your class and expose more granular operations that you will use in an external loop.

so an example would be:

```
class Stopwatch {
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    int seconds; 
};   

Stopwatch::Stopwatch() : hours(0), minutes(0), seconds(0) {}

void Stopwatch::reset() {
    // Initialize all time values to zero
}

int getElapsedMinutes() {
    return this->minutes;
}

void Stopwatch::updateClock() {
    h = hours < 10 ? "0" : "";
    s = seconds < 10 ? "0" : "";
    m = minutes < 10 ? "0" : "";
    cout << h << hours << " : " << m << minutes << " : " << s << seconds;
    Sleep(1000);
    system("cls");
    seconds++;
    if (seconds == 60) {
        minutes++;
        seconds = 0;
        if (minutes == 60) {
            hours++;
            seconds = 0;
            minutes = 0;
        }
    }
}

bool checkForStopCondition(StopWatch sw) {
    // Will stop the timer when it reaches 2 minutes
    return sw.getElapsedMinutes() >= 2;
}

int main(int, char**) {
    Stopwatch sw;
    bool exit = false;
    while(!exit) {
        sw.updateClock();
        exit = checkForStopCondition(sw);
    }
}
```

Note: This is untested and only one of many possible solutions and it won't accurately measure time, but neither does your current implementation.

Comment: What is a purpose of checkForStopCondition() method? I mean, your code still doesnt make sense cause of infinity loop. Or I just dont get something u trying to say...

Comment: I've clarified my solution, but Andriy Tylychko's answer seems to address more the spirit of your problem

Answer (score 0):

"Counting" time yourself is the worst idea ever. Use "difference between time snapshots" apporoach. chrono, time+difftime, whatever. You should not worry about libs because they are standard calls like cout or printf.